# Can't use DataSource after lookup

Tags: java, sql-server, junit, jndi

I am creating a JUnit to test a part of the application that uses Apache Shiro for authentication, for this I am creating a `SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource` and binding it.

The problem happens when I try to lookup the `DataSource` and get a connection, it fails the authentication of the user configured in the `SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource`.

After analyzing the `DataSource` before the bind and after the lookup it appears the only difference is that the one I got from the lookup don't have the password data in it.

this is the code I am using:

```
System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.apache.naming");

InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

ic.createSubcontext("jdbc");

// Construct DataSource
SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource();

ds.setURL("URL");
ds.setUser("USER");
ds.setPassword("PASSWORD");

ic.bind("jdbc/mentorweb", ds);

DataSource dsb = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/mentorweb");

Connection conn = dsb.getConnection();
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a context with

```
ic.createSubcontext("java:comp/env/jdbc");
...
ic.bind("java:comp/env/jdbc/mentorweb", ds);
```

Comment: The context works the same way with the extra paths, I can get the DataSource but it don't connect.